# iPhone: Flipping View like the Weather App?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller, flip

Can someone advise the codes or similar codes for the iPhone weather page, when you touch the little circled (i) the right, bottom corner, it flips the page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In XCode, File -> New Project... -> Utility Application.

Answer (score 2):

What the weather app does is: it just presents a modal view controller, but sets the transition style to a different value.
The following assumes the controller you want to show is simply named "controller" and shows the controllers view similarly to the weather app.

```
controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```